# FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_FILE

Tags: java, android

I want to get videos from the gallery but I have a problem that shows the general memory of the phone, how can I solve it?

```
 private void selectVideo()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, FastScrollerFilePickerActivity.class);

    i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
    i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_ALLOW_CREATE_DIR, false);
    i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_MODE, FilePickerActivity.MODE_FILE);

    String searchFolder;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String fileSearchPath = prefs.getString("fileSearchPath", "last-used");

    switch(fileSearchPath)
    {
        case "last-used":
        default:
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
            searchFolder = prefs.getString(PICKER_DIR_PREF, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
            break;

        case "external":
            searchFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            break;
    }

    i.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_START_PATH, searchFolder);
    startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_FILE_REQUEST);
}
```

I want to get videos from the gallery but I have a problem that shows the general memory of the phone, how can I solve it?

```
protected AbstractFilePickerFragment getFragment(@Nullable String startPath, int mode, boolean allowMultiple, boolean allowCreateDir, boolean allowExistingFile, boolean singleClick)
    {
        return getFragment(startPath, mode, allowMultiple, allowCreateDir);
    }

    protected AbstractFilePickerFragment<File> getFragment(
            @Nullable final String startPath, final int mode, final boolean allowMultiple,
            final boolean allowCreateDir) {
        AbstractFilePickerFragment<File> fragment = new FastScrollerFilePickerFragment();
        // startPath is allowed to be null. In that case, default folder should be SD-card and not "/"
        fragment.setArgs(startPath != null ? startPath : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
                mode, allowMultiple, allowCreateDir, true, false);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: write here the error message you're getting

Comment: I'm not getting an error taking you to the video gallery and not the files. I couldn't figure out where.

Comment: Ask the developer of `FastScrollerFilePickerActivity`.

Comment: i added, at last one

Comment: chooses from the gallery but this time the application closes itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the video picker with the following line

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
SELECT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

If your app crashes it must leave red colored messages in the `Logcat`, which can be very helpful in trying to get your understand the problem.

Now in your `onActivityResult` method put the following to get the path of video you selected:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    if(reqCode == SELECT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE){
      Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String videoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: chooses from the gallery but this time the application closes itself.